# Realm: How to add two Results<(Object)> in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For arrays we could just do

```
resultArray = array1 + array2
```

I have two results of Results<(Object)> how do I add them?

Do I have to loop or is there in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Results` does not support concatenation, but you can create a `GeneratorOf` that will yield the sum of the two results, or create an `[Object]` that is the non-lazy equivalent of that by doing

```
let sum = map(array1) { $0 } + map(array2) { $0}
```

Comment: This syntax is out of date... This should work: foos.map{$0 as Foo} + bars.map{$0 as Bar}

Answer (score 3):

`RLMResults` are like array but not array, so you cannot add them directly, you have to use predicates to get your results. This is mentioned in [Realm Doc](https://realm.io/docs/objc/0.92.2/api/Classes/RLMResults.html#class_methods)

> RLMResults is an auto-updating container type in Realm returned from object queries.
>
> RLMResults can be queried with the same predicates as RLMObject and RLMArray and you can chain queries to further filter query results.
>
> RLMResults cannot be created directly.

But If you want to add objects of `RLMArray` or `RLMResults` in an existing `RLMArray` you can use `– addObjects:` method of `RLMArray` only condition is that both the results should be of the same class. [RLMArray Doc](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#//api/name/addObjects:) for reference.

Comment: Results<Object> does not have addObjects() method.

Comment: RLMArray contains addObjects: method, so you can use. If you are trying to add or append two RMLResults, its not possible, as stated in Realm Docs.